# Dividing the length by sin(x) always results in a negative answer

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int caltype;
int numorden;
int length, angle;

cout << "Type '1' for sine, '2' for cosine and '3' for tangent." << endl;
cin >> caltype;

switch (caltype) {
    case 1:
        cout << "Is the unknown length the numerator or the denominator? Type '1' for numerator and '2' for denominator." << endl;
        cin >> numorden;

        switch (numorden) {
            case 1:
                cout << "Type the length of the hypotenuse." << endl;
                cin >> length;
                cout << "Type in the angle." << endl;
                cin >> angle;
                cout << "sinangle = O/H" << endl;
                cout << "sin" << angle << " = x/" << length << endl;
                cout << length << "sin" << angle << " = x" << endl;
                cout << "Therefore x = " << length *sin (angle);
                break;
            case 2:
                cout << "Type the length of the opposite." << endl;
                cin >> length;
                cout << "Type in the angle." << endl;
                cin >> angle;
                cout << "sinangle = O/H" << endl;
                cout << "sin" << angle << " = " << length << "/x" << endl;
                cout << "xsin" << angle << " = " << length << endl;
                cout << "Therefore x = " << length / sin (angle);
        }
}

}
```

What I am making right now is a program that will show you the steps when it is doing trigonometry. For some reason, when the opposite is divided by, lets say, sin(30), it always results in a negative number. Why is that? The error appears to be occurring at this line:

```
    cout << "Therefore x = " << length / sin (angle);
```

Comment: Are you aware that the angle for `sin` and the like must be in radians, not in degrees?

Comment: You may want to be explicit about the units of the angle. `cout << "Type in the angle in degrees." << endl;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to convert it to radians:

`sin (angle * PI/180);`

**UPDATE:**

[What is PI?](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/83485/)

[World Record values of PI](http://www.numberworld.org/digits/Pi/)

Comment: sorry, but what does PI mean? I had only just started learning trigonometry.

Comment: In short terms it is the ratio of the circumference of a circle to its diameter -- a really important parameter, at the core of much of the progress mankind has made since the discovery of the wheel....

Answer (score 0):

The `sin` function takes input as radian:

```
sin (angle * M_PI/180);
```

where M_PI = 3.141...., which is a constant.