# How to rotate a point every second

Tags: c++, sdl-2

I have a point that I want to rotate that corresponds to every second in time like a second hand in a clock, it should rotate 6 degrees every second but i tried timing it and it does not take a minute to make a full rotation, here is the code

```
void rotate(const float& ox, const float& oy, float &x, float &y, const float& rotation) {
float tx = x-ox;
float ty = y-oy;
float nx = tx*cos(rotation) - ty*sin(rotation);
float ny = tx*sin(rotation) + ty*cos(rotation);
x = nx+ox;
y = ny+oy;
}

float origx = 1280/2, origy = 720/2, pntx = origx, pnty = origy-300, rotation=6; // variables

rotate(origx, origy, pntx, pnty, rotation*timer.delta); // update point, timer is an object that gets the delta time between frames of the main loop
```

Comment: Wait is this Unreal?

Comment: this is in sdl2

Comment: Why are you passing all arguments by reference? For simple types (like `int` or `float`) there's really no meaning in passing as `const` references.

Comment: What exactly is your question? Is the code you posted not working?

Comment: I dont want to return something so I change the values inside the function

Comment: Your code doesn't show your timing.  You say you want it to take 1 second to go 6 degrees but we don't know if you have a `sleep` or what in the code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dividing the length by sin(x) always results in a negative answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49483896/dividing-the-length-by-sinx-always-results-in-a-negative-answer)

Comment: For example, the `ox` argument, it's a reference to a *constant* floating point value. You *can't* change that. So why pass it by reference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need to update the values for your variables like:

- your `origx` should be `90 deg` which is `0.5π rad`
- your `origy` should also be `90 deg` which is `0.5π rad`
- every second step (`rotation`) is `6 deg` which is `0.033333333333π rad`

For [`sin`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/sin/) and [`cos`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/cos/) takes **radians** in the argument and not degrees.

Comment: I assumed the sin and cos functions of c++ takes in degrees, I read the reference it turns out it takes in radians!